# Google People API returns mostly empty results

Tags: php, google-people-api

I'm using Google People (via the PHP api) to receive a list of contacts for the current user, using `people.connections.list` on `people/me`. A limited number of the contacts (about 30 out of around 270) are populated with the expected fields (names, phone numbers) but all the rest just look like this:

```
 {
  "resourceName": "people/c2291334562690757834",
  "etag": "%EgUBAgs3LhoMAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMIgxyMldWMWJrWW1wUT0="
},
{
  "resourceName": "people/c2389043395746324575",
  "etag": "%EgUBAgs3LhoMAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMIgxtaTVEakJwNk5HTT0="
},
{
  "resourceName": "people/c2509199125868025440",
  "etag": "%EgUBAgs3LhoMAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMIgwwekJiSlJtR3JSRT0="
},
```

I'd post my PHP code but I get exactly the same output from the 'Try This API' panel at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list.

I'm tearing my hair out here! Any ideas? I honestly can't see what's special or different about the ones which are returned. If I create a new contact directly in Google Contacts (Name: Bob Test, Phone: +447777 777777), it doesn't show any detail either.

Comment: Generally, if the contact doesn't have the fields you requested (e.g. a contact with no name or phone number), it returns the contact with just the resourceName and etag set.

How did you verify that the new contact you created didn't have any details? e.g. did you find the contact with the corresponding ID? If you did a text search, make sure that you are using a large enough page size (or make multiple requests) to get all your contacts.

Comment: The contacts all have the data I'm requesting. Page size is fine; all contacts are returned. It's just that the majority contain no details. When I inspect the contacts within the Google Contacts UI, there is absolutely no difference between one that works (name, email and phone number) and one that doesn't (name, email and phone number). No weird characters, no difference in phone numbers, no group differences - nothing. They are all contacts I use day to day on phone and email.

Comment: Maybe I can use a different approach? The only reason I'm listing contacts is to match by contact name. Is there a call I can use to just retrieve details for a particular contact by name? I have to say I'm not impressed by the People API compared to the Contact API, at least in terms of Contact functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API for searching contacts yet. I am unable to reproduce your example. Please file a bug request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=344199&template=1041029

Comment: Thanks Amos, I have raised an issue as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I too have wasted way to much time on this problem.  The new Contacts -> People API migration hasn't been too smooth.  The good news is I've found I get much better results using the `otherContacts.list` api: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list

It shows my contacts as I'd expect including names fields.  Maybe give that a try instead?  I also have terrible results with people.listDirectoryPeople (yes we are a workplace org).